# ng-repeat not working AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

Both the ng-repeat's are not working. But just showing {{ rows }} does work. So the communication between the template and the controller is working.

What's wrong with my `ng-repeat`?

I already searched the other posts on this topic, but on all of them the error was in the controller. But even repeating an I in an array defined in the HTML template isn't working. And the Rows are showing up when not looping.

```
<div ng-controller="OrderNewCtrl">

  <h1> {{ rows }}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="i in [42, 42, 43, 43]">
    {{ i }}
    <p>test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows">
            {{rowContent}}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-functionality btn-success btn-add" ng-click="addRow">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.orderNew', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/order/new', {
    templateUrl: 'order-new/order-new.template.html',
    controller: 'OrderNewCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('OrderNewCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'];
  $scope.counter = 4;
  $scope.test = "hi";

  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.rows.push('Row ' + $scope.counter);
    $scope.counter++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are working fine, just use the `(key, value)` separator on your index based arrays.

```
<div ng-controller="OrderNewCtrl">
  <h1> {{ rows }}</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in [42, 42, 43, 43]">
    {{ key }}
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="(rowContent, value) in rows">
            {{rowContent}}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-functionality btn-success btn-add" ng-click="addRow">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using track by For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'] track by $index">
    {{n}}
</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hMzexutE6fqicn3KVkFE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

1. Problem with your html - you are not using `td` inside `tr`

   `<tr ng-repeat="rowContent in rows track by $index">
     <td>{{rowContent}}</td>
   </tr>`
2. you have duplicate values in the list - use `track by $index` in `ng-repeat`

   `ng-repeat="i in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index"`

   `ng-repeat="rowContent in rows track by $index"`